# How does party matchmaking work?

Tags: dota-2

If I queue with 4 friends (making us a full 5 people team), do we get matchmade (?) with another 5 people team, or is it possible to fight 5 people that do not know each other?

Comment: You're more likely to meet another party or at least a couple of groups, but they haven't revealed any details on how likely.

Comment: They've released details, now: http://blog.dota2.com/2013/12/matchmaking/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After playing over 1000 games, my and my friends experience is: **You can be matched with and against any formation of players.**

But when playing with a Party of 5 against 5 Individual Players, these Individuals may be of a higher skill rating then you, to compensate your improved communication. This is a common practice in Matchmaking Algorithms and all data seems to support Dota 2 works the same way.

Answer (score 1):

We got in a match with a team of 5 people and our team are people who don't know each other, so most likely, matchmaking is like filling slots for players.

Answer (score 0):

You will be matched with 5 players whom may or may not be "premade" (that is, people who know each other who game together, like you and your 4 friends). 
The matchmaking system does not yet take into account premade players in any way.